# Rectangle.y issue, persistently rendering at 0

Tags: java, swing, awt, coordinates, rectangles

I'm trying to render a rectangle to a JPanel:

```
playerRect = new Rectangle(100,100,10,10);
```

Problem is, playerRect renders at 100,0 every time. I've updated Eclipse and Java, as well as troubleshoot my code and played with the x, y, width, height (although I'm not sure how my code could affect java.awt.Rectangle).

Any clue as to what is causing this?

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player {

private World world;
private Rectangle playerRect;
private Image playerImg;

protected int xDirection, yDirection; 

//block variables
private int hoverX, hoverY;
private boolean hovering;

public Player(World world){
    this.world = world;
    playerImg = new ImageIcon("D:/Student Data/gametest1/GameEngine/res/player.png").getImage();

    playerRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 10, 10); //  ### here's the issue ###

}


private void setXDirection(int d){
    xDirection = d;
}

private void setYDirection(int d){
    yDirection = d;
}

public void update(){
    move();
    checkForCollision();
}

private void move(){
    playerRect.x += xDirection;
    playerRect.y =+ yDirection;


}

private void checkForCollision(){

}


//Drawing methods
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(playerImg, playerRect.x, playerRect.y, null);
}

private void drawBlackOutline(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(hoverX,hoverY, world.blocks[0].width, world.blocks[0].height);
    if(hovering){drawBlackOutline(g);}
}

//mouse events
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    int px = playerRect.x;
    int py = playerRect.y;
    for(int i =0; i <world.arrayNum; i++){
        if(world.blocks[i].contains(x,y)){
            hovering = true;
            hoverX = world.blocks[i].x;
            hoverY = world.blocks[i].y;
            break;
        }else{hovering = false;}
    }



}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

}



private class Weapon{
    public static final int UNARMED = 0;
    public static final int PICKAXE = 1;
    public static final int GUN = 2;

    public int CURRENT_WEAPON;

    public Weapon( int w){
        switch(w){
            default:
                System.out.println("no weapon sellected");
                break;
            case UNARMED:
                CURRENT_WEAPON = UNARMED;
                break;
            case PICKAXE:
                CURRENT_WEAPON = PICKAXE;
                break;
            case GUN:
                CURRENT_WEAPON = GUN;
                break;
        }
    }


    public void selectWeapon( int w){
        switch(w){
        default:
            System.out.println("no weapon sellected");
            break;
        case UNARMED:
            CURRENT_WEAPON = UNARMED;
            break;
        case PICKAXE:
            CURRENT_WEAPON = PICKAXE;
            break;
        case GUN:
            CURRENT_WEAPON = GUN;
            break;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEquipped(int w){
        if(w == CURRENT_WEAPON){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
}
```

Here's where the rectangle is drawn to the JPanel:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//Double Buffering
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;
//JPanel variables
static final int GWIDTH = 900, GHEIGHT = 600;
static final Dimension gameDim = new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
//Game variables
private Thread game;
private volatile boolean running = false;
public int tickCount = 0;

private static final int DELAYS_BEFORE_YIELD = 10;
private long period = 6*1000000; //ms --> nano

//Game Objects
World world;
Player p1;


public GamePanel(){
    world = new World();
    p1 = new Player(world);
    setPreferredSize(gameDim);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    //Handle all key inputs from user
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                world.navigateMap(World.PAN_UP);}

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            world.navigateMap(World.PAN_DOWN);}

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            world.navigateMap(World.PAN_LEFT);}

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            world.navigateMap(World.PAN_RIGHT);}
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            world.stopMoveMap();
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }

    });

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
            p1.mouseMoved(e);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){

        }
    });

}


private void startGame(){
    if(game == null || !running){
        game = new Thread(this);
        game.start();
        running = true;
    }
}

public void addNotify(){
    super.addNotify();
    startGame();
}

public void stopGame(){

    if(running){
        running = false;

    }
}


public void run() {

long lastTime = System.nanoTime();


    long beforeTime, afterTime, diff, sleepTime, overSleepTime = 0;
    int delays = 0;
    while(running){
        beforeTime =System.nanoTime();
        gameUpdate();
        gameRender();
        paintScreen();
        afterTime = System.nanoTime();
        diff = afterTime - beforeTime;
        sleepTime = (period - diff) - overSleepTime;
        //if the sleep time is between 0 and the period, sleep
        if(sleepTime < period && sleepTime > 0){
            try {
                game.sleep(sleepTime/1000000L);
                overSleepTime = 0;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("You done goofed!");
            }

        } 
        //the difference was greater than the period
        else if(diff>period){
            overSleepTime = diff - period;
        }
        //accumulate the amount of delays, and eventually yield
        else if(++delays >= DELAYS_BEFORE_YIELD){
            game.yield();
        }
        //the loop took less time than expected,but we need to make up for            oversleep time
        else{overSleepTime = 0;}}
        }



private void gameUpdate(){
    if(running && game != null){
        //update game state
        world.moveMap();
        p1.update();
    }
}

private void gameRender(){
    if(dbImage == null){ //create the buffer
        dbImage = createImage(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
        if(dbImage == null){
            System.err.println("dbImage is still null!");
            return;
        }else{
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        }
    }
//Clear the screen
    dbg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    dbg.fillRect(0, 0, GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
//Draw Game elements
    draw(dbg);
}

//#####   Draw all game content in this method   #####//
public void draw(Graphics g){
    world.draw(g);
    p1.draw(g);
    //g.setColor(Color.RED);
    //g.setFont(new Font("PR Celtic Narrow", Font.BOLD, 50));
    //String str = "MentalBrink Lv. 5";
    //g.drawString(str, 100,100);


}

private void paintScreen(){
    Graphics g;
    try{
        g = this.getGraphics();
        if(dbImage != null && g != null){
            g.drawImage(dbImage,  0,  0, null);
        }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); //for Linux people. 
        g.dispose();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }

}

private void log(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code of where you actually draw the rectangle?

Comment: I've added class where issue occurs and where the rectangle is drawn.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).